# Can't Move Cursor Within Text in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

I found somehow similar questions on stack overflow.. but all of them didn't work with me..

I hope someone can help me with my problem.. The problem is that I can't move the cursor within the text of the EditText if I set the gravity of my EditText to right *and I really need to do that* the cursor is stick to the right of each line I touch and doesn't move to the specific character I am touching..

This problem occur on platforms 4.1.2 and before.. I don't have this problem with 4.2.2

if I removed the gravity attribute every thing works fine and i can place the cursor wherever i want..

Any Suggestion I can do this with keeping my gravity attribute?

Thanks in advance,